# Laravel Lighthouse PHP Call to undefined relationship - but only on server

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I'm developing an app that uses Lighthouse GraphQL server for Laravel. It's generally great, but I've run into some  weird behaviour.

When I run it locally, using Laravel Valet, it works perfectly. When I run it on staging server, it fails with `Call to undefined relationship [venue] on model [App\\Event].`
Event has one Venue and Venue can have many events.

When I use tinker on the server, it finds relationships fine.

Relationship on Event is setup like this

```
public function venue() : BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Venue');
}
```

And relationship on Venue is

```
 public function events() : HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Event', 'venue_id');
}
```

In schema.graphql relationship is defined as

```
 type Event {
    id: ID!
    [...]
    venue: Venue @belongsTo
}
```

And other relationships work fine.
Same versions locally and on staging.

Any idea as to what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here. It turned out to be a difference in Laravel version that apparently caused the problem. A minor version at that.

Fixed the problem by locking the version for now and getting back to it in next release.

Comment: What version were you on, and what version did you lock it to to fix the issue?